# Count values with the same value inside loop

Tags: php, loops, explode

I try count elements inside loop, with the same value, as i put in my title, now i show my little script fot try to do this :

```
<?php
$values="1,2,3~4,5,2~7,2,9";

$expt=explode("~",$values);

foreach ($expt as $expts)
{

$expunit=explode(",",$expts);


$bb="no";

foreach($expunit as $expunits)
{

//// $expunit[1] it´s the second value in each explode

if ($expunits==="".$expunit[1]."")
{
$bb="yes";
}

if ($bb=="yes")
{
print "$expunits --- $expunit[1] ok, value it´s the same<br>";
}
else
{
print " $expunits bad, value it´s not the same<br>";
}

}

}

?>
```

**THE SCRIPT MUST SHOW DATA IN THIS WAY :**

```
  $values="1,2,3~4,5,2~7,2,9";
```

**FIRST ELEMENTS WITH THE SAME SECOND ELEMENT, IN VALUES COMMON VALUE IT´S NUMBER 2, BECAUSE IT´S IN SECOND POSITION **

**FIRST :**

```
1,2,3
7,2,9
```

**LAST THE OTHERS**

```
4,5,2
```

I try verificate the second position, between delimeters, because it´s value i want verificate for count inside loop, while explode string, actually give bad values, i think it´s bad because don´t get real or right values, i don´t know if it´s possible do it or with other script or change something in this

Thank´s Regards

Comment: Constructive criticism: You may want to properly indent your code and space it out a little better for readability.

Comment: If you can put example perfect please, thank´s

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? `if ($expunits==="".$expunit[1]."")` 
Since you are wrapping `$expunit[1]` inside two empty strings, `"".` on either side effectively does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - this is a bit closer to what you are looking for (sorry it is not perfect as I do not have time to work on it fully):

```
$values="1,2,3~4,5,2~7,2,9";
$values=explode("~",$values);
foreach($values as $key => $expt) {
  $expit=explode(",",$expt);
  $search_value = $expit[1];
  $matched=array();
  foreach($values as $key2 => $expt2) {
    if($key !== $key2) {
      $expit2=explode(",",$expt2);
      if($expit[1]==$expit2[1]) {
        $matched[] = $expit[1];
      }
    }
  }
}
array_unique($matched);
foreach($matched as $match) {
  $counter = 0;
  $no_matches = array();
  echo "<br />Matching on digit ".$match;
  foreach($values as $key3 => $expt3) {
    $expit3=explode(",",$expt3);
    if($match == $expit3[1]) {
      echo "<br />".$expt3;
      $counter++;
    } else {
      $no_matches[] = $expt3;
    }
  }
  echo "<br />Total number of matches - ".$counter;
  echo "<br />Not matching on digit ".$match;
  foreach($no_matches as $no_match) {
    echo "<br />".$no_match;
  }
}
```

Outputs:

Matching on digit 2

1,2,3

7,2,9

Total number of matches - 2

Not matching on digit 2

4,5,2

Comment: Yes but i need explode first for "~" and after this explode in each case by ",", if you replace ~by , it´s problem because the values separate by "~" and need see the same values in position 2 when explode by "~" , regards and thank´s

Comment: So you are looking to explode at the ~ to get 1,2,3 and 4,5,2. Then, in each group you are seeing if the second number repeats inside each group? Or is repeated in any other group? Either way is possible, so just let me know and I can show you the code. Thanks.

Comment: Yes the delimeter between data it´s "~" and for navigate between data delimeter it´s "," the common data for comparate it´s the data in second position, the script must works show in first place all data with the second data position it´s the same , and after, the other data no have second position data in common , no more, i go to put in the example the order for this results, thank´s for your help

Comment: @Anton I edited my answer to get closer to what you are looking for. Now as for the output, did you want a count, just the matching triplets, or all values with a label of matching or not?

Comment: It´s great, i give you thank´s alot for understand i want and help me with this, thank´s, thank´s, thank´s

Comment: Glad I could help. If it doesn't meet your requirements exactly, feel free to let me know!